Firebase In-App-Message A/B Test Frequency Limit
we are using Firebase In-App-Messages and also want to A/B test some messages. Everything is clear BUT there is no option to set the frequency limit for these tests (for campaigns it is possible).
What is the frequency limit for In-App-Messages using A/B tests? Is it once per day or once per device or each time an event is triggered?
I cannot find any info in the web or the documentation, but it is essential to understand when users may be eligible to be impressed.
I did receive the in app message usign the test and it did not show the message each time the event was triggered. But I cannot be sure what the default frequency limit is.
